# SSL Certificate Error while making a POST request to an external server

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, post, python-requests, ssl-certificate

Am trying to make a post request to https://app.getswift.co/api/public/v2/deliveries using requests library and I get the following error

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='app.getswift.co', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /api/public/v2/deliveries (Caused by SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'app.getswift.co' doesn't match either of '*.my_domain.ai', 'another.my_domain.ai'),))
```

This is the request I make.

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
}

data = {
    "apiKey": "my-api-key",
    "booking": {
        "pickupDetail": {
            "name": "Rupert 1",
            "phone": "1234567890",
            "address": "112 luscombe st, brunswick, melbourne"
        },
        "dropoffDetail": {
            "name": "Igor 2",
            "phone": "0987654321",
            "address": "105 collins st, 3000"
        }
    }
}
requests.post("https://app.getswift.co/api/public/v2/deliveries", headers=headers, json=data)
```

I tested the same code on my local, python shell and even making a postman request, it works perfectly fine. The problem comes when I try to push the same code to ec2 server and make the post request call.

I tried using `verify=False` to see if it works(even though I know the security consequences) but instead, I get `"404 Not found"`.
This is what I see on my ec2 logs

```
Not Found: /api/public/v2/deliveries 

HTTP POST /api/public/v2/deliveries 404 [0.01, 127.0.0.1:57840] 
https://app.getswift.co:443 "POST /api/public/v2/deliveries HTTP/1.1" 404 None
```

I'll be grateful to any help.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without accessing the exact page, but could you add the other headers such as User-Agent and the `cookies=cookies`? I think the page might be checking for authentication and you are not properly authenticating.

Otherwise, it could be also be that the ec2 server is behind a proxy/vpn like AWS servers can be. In that case, you can try to trust the environment.

```
s = requests.Session()
s.trust_env = False

response = s.get("https://app.getswift.co/api/public/v2/deliveries", headers=headers, json=data)
```

If it doesn't work then the API might simply be blocking your ec2 server. Try another making a ec2 in another region or use another VPS and see if it works.

Comment: "verfiry=False" gives "404 not found" as mentioned in the question

Comment: how come it works from my local, postman and from the python shell without the other headers?

Comment: True that. It's hard to guess without having access to the webpage, so I've added another guess, not sure if it'll work for you.

Comment: I tried your solution with trust_env False but it gave the same SSLError. Actually there is no webpage to this, when I receive an order, I make this request to send the order details to the server from the backend.